# Jquery set attribute to every element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set attribute of every a tag as img tag's src.

Here is what I did.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var href=$('.single img').attr('src');
 $('.single').attr('href',href);
 $(".single").fancybox({
          helpers: {
              title : {
                  type : 'float'
              }
          }
      });
      
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<a class="single" >
 <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1661/24170619595_ca34ef74d9_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="single" >
 <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1514/23919332220_60b7867d60_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="single" >
 <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1669/23976340262_a5ca3859f6_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="single" >
 <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1459/23610702803_83655c7c56_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

But every a tag has same href.

How can I fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go through all of the images and assign it one by one (That's using your own code). 
You can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".single img").each(function() {
        var href=$(this).attr('src');
        $(this).parent().attr('href',href);
    })

    $(".single").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            title : {
                type : 'float'
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** with callback, which iterate over the elements and update the attribute by getting children `img` attribute value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.single').attr('href', function() { // iterate over a tag
    return $(this)
    .find('img') // get children img
    .attr('src') // get arc attribute
  });
  $(".single").fancybox({
    helpers: {
      title: {
        type: 'float'
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<a class="single">
  <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1661/24170619595_ca34ef74d9_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="single">
  <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1514/23919332220_60b7867d60_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="single">
  <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1669/23976340262_a5ca3859f6_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="single">
  <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1459/23610702803_83655c7c56_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```